# Can I access the contents of a shared container on my iOS device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager

How can we see the contents of the shared app group container  of my iOS application on my iPad. I have tried locating the app container from the Organizer, but the shared app group container (of identifier group.com.company.xxx) was not there in the directory contents.

Example code for generating URL for stored container:

```
NSURL *containerURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                       containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"group.com.me.myapp"];

NSURL *storeURL = [containerURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.sqlite"];
```

Comment: Did you enable "App Groups" Capabilities?

Comment: Yes, i have enabled the App groups.I wanted to see the contents inside the app group shared container.

Answer (score 0):

You code should be like this.

```
NSURL *containerURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                       containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"group.com.me.myapp"];

NSString *storeURL = [[containerURL path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.sqlite"];
```